# How to open link with movieclip? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a textarea that will have a hyperlink to youtube videos. I have a movieclip that is used as a youtube player. How can I do it so where when a user clicks a youtube like in the textarea that instead of navigating with the browser, it sends that link to my movieclip?

Also, this textarea will have normal hyperlinks that will need to be clicked and handled normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you need to catch user's click on specific link.

In AS2 you could write special code in href parameter of html tag "a":

```
<a href="asfunction:your_function_name,param">
```

In AS3 you can trigger event in similar way:

```
<a href="event:myLink">example text</a>
```

In this case, TextField will dispatch TextEvent.LINK with "myLink" in `text` property

The completed example:

```
mText.htmlText = '<a href="event:myLink">example text</a>';
mText.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, textEvent)
function textEvent(event:TextEvent) : void {
    trace('link to '+event.text);
}
```